# Spring JMX. Set the default value of @ManagedAtrribute through XML

Tags: java, spring, jmx

I'm using Spring 3.0.5

I have a @ManagedResource bean, for some of the @ManagedAttribute methods which I want to set a defaultValue. Instead of setting it to a hardcoded value I want to be able to read it from a property value at load time, since the default changes from environment to environment.

A snippet from my programs applicationContext.xml:

```
<context:mbean-export default-domain="sampleApp"/>
<bean id="managedBean" class="com.example.sampleBean">
    <constructor-arg value="Sample Bean"/>
    <constructor-arg value="${sample.property}"/>
</bean>
```

I believe I have to use the XML configuration to be able to do this, but haven't figured out how to do it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to your applicationContext.xml, it should expose the properties you are after:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>
```

So if the application.properties file you are pointing to above contains a property called sample.property then Spring will use that to inject into your ${sample.property} placeholder.

For more details you can see the Spring reference [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer).